# Parallax Effect: Make foreground move when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have a few images that I'd like to lay out on a page vertically as a bit of an info-graphic. However, I'd like to separate the background from the foreground elements and have a bit of a parallax effect where as you scroll down, the foreground (of background) elements move ...

Not sure how best to accomplish this with jQuery or even CSS3 ... any links or examples would be most appreciated.

Comment: Seriously ... close? Either help or don't. Goodness.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum. You provide code, we look over the code for errors and report back with a solution. This doesn't meet the criteria, therefore it needs to be closed. -1

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**jquery.parallax**](https://stephen.band/jparallax/).

> jParallax turns nodes into absolutely positioned layers that move in response to the mouse. Depending on their dimensions these layers move at different rates, in a parallaxy kind of way.

**Screenshot** of how it would be:

[image: jQParallax]
<sub>(source: [stephband.info](http://stephband.info/jparallax/images/diagram.png))</sub>

The **code** is small too.

```
<ul>
    <li class="parallax-layer"></li>
    <li class="parallax-layer"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer, there are much more simpler and good plugins:

1. [(Almost) Static Background](https://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/)

   [image]
2. [Curtain.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616193223/http://curtain.victorcoulon.fr:80/)

   http://www.jquerythisplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/curtain.jpg
3. [StellarJS](https://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/)

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [jquer.in](http://jquer.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/stellar-js.jpg))</sub>
4. [scrolldeck](https://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/)

   [image]
5. [SCROLLORAMA](https://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)

   [image]
   <sub>(source: [romanliutikov.com](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/scrollorama.png))</sub>
6. [ParallaxSlider](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ParallaxSlider/)

   [image]